# General Schwarz Lemma

Tags: complex-analysis

I need to use general form of Schwarz lemma to show that $\frac{|f'(z)|}{(1-|f(z)|^2)}$ $\leq$ $\frac{1}{1 - |z|^2}$

The original Schwarz lemma states that:  if f(z) is analytic for |z| $<$ 1 and satisfies the conditions |f(z)| $\leq$ 1 and f(0) = 0, then |f(z)| $\leq$ |z| and |f '(0)| $\leq$ 1

How to derive the general form of this lemma and prove the above result?

I read some material from Ahlfors: " if f(z) is known to satisfy the conditions of the theorem in a disk of radius R, , the original form of the theorem can be applied to function f(Rz). As a result , we obtain |f(Rz)| $\leq$ |z|. Similarly, if the upper bound of the modulus is M instead of 1, apply theorem to f(Rz)/M"

But I still feel confusing how to do it.

Comment: Do you know about Mobius transformations that map the disk to itself?

Comment: See [Proof of Schwarz–Pick theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma#Proof_of_Schwarz–Pick_theorem)

Comment: rearrange the left-hand side into the difference quotient and let z2 tend to z1,  still cannot figure it out